# How to get the name of the previous page from redirected page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the name of the previous page, but the problem is that my code is unable to get the name of the previous page. For example, I have two pages `Previous.aspx` and `Next.aspx`. In `Next.aspx` page I want the page name of the page URL `Previous.aspx`. How can I do this? I have tried with the following code in `Next.aspx` page.

```
public string GetPreviousPageName()
{
    string Path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
    System.IO.FileInfo Info = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path);
    string pageName = Info.Name;
    return pageName;
}
```

Comment: You mean title tag? Page.Title.

Comment: @Tuğrul  yes, I want page title

Comment: I would use Cookies. Save  & load. Cookies["title"]=Page.Title;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can achive this:

1.You have to store somewhere URL of page you want to recall, for example using ViewState in Page_Load() method:

```
if( !IsPostBack )
{
     ViewState["ReferrerUrl"]  = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
}
```

2.Retrieve url from ViewState:

```
 string referrerUrl = (string) ViewState["ReferrerUrl"];
```

3.Get name of page with this url:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(referrerUrl);
string pageName = fileInfo.Name;
```

Comment: Exception occurs in this line  System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(referrerUrl);   that value cannot be null Parameter name: fileName

Comment: Thanx @Kao It's run perfectly. I had correct my exception problem

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
// Home is default controller
      var controller = (Request.UrlReferrer.Segments.Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault() ?? "Home").Trim('/');
// Index is default action 
      var action = (Request.UrlReferrer.Segments.Skip(2).Take(1).SingleOrDefault() ?? "Index").Trim('/');
```

In Authorization Class

```
     var Url= filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
// Home is default controller
     var OldcontrollerAuth = (((Url != null) ? Url.Segments.Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault() : "Home") ?? "Home").Trim('/');
// Index is default action 
     var OldActionAuth = (((Url != null) ? Url.Segments.Skip(2).Take(1).SingleOrDefault() : "/") ?? "/").Trim('/');
```